# Reliable Serial Communication Arduino to RPi

Tags: python, serial-port, raspberry-pi, usb

I'm trying to send a string of data from the Arduino to the RPi and then try to separate the string with `var1, var2, var3, var4 = line.split(",")`

The Arduino is sending me a constant stream of variables in a format like this `var1,var2,var3,var4var1,var2,var3,var4var1` but I only want to select the variables the way I posted above. How do I do it? How do I time when the RPi reads what is coming in from the Serial port?

This is the way I read the serial data.

```
ard = serial.Serial(port="/dev/ttyACM0", baudrate=9600)
while True:
    line = ard.readline()
    print line
    var1, var2, var3, var4 = line.split(",")
    break
ard.close()
```

but sometimes I receive the string like this var2,var3,var4var1 or var4var1,var2,var3 or something random like var1var2.

How do I fix it? What do I have to do that I will always receive the variables in this format `var1,var2,var3,var4`

I've heard I can do start and end characters like !var1,var2,var3,var4? but I don't know how to implement a working code.

Comment: What's the purpose of this `while True:` / `break` combination which will always break?

Comment: @KlausD. because I thought it otherwise stays in the loop, when I remove it all the strings get print but I don't advance to the other parts of my program

Comment: When you say "__but I don't know how to implement a working code__", do you speak about the Arduino source code ? What is the periodicity of the message `var1,var2,var3,var4` ?

Comment: @J.Piquard Hello, thanks for trying help but I fixed my problem. What I did was always discard the first line of the serial data and use the second for formatting, which worked. the first line was always corrupted but by simply discarding it I went around that.